# Why might client app throw "No route to host" SocketException?

Tags: flutter

While looking at remote logs of my mobile (flutter) app I noticed that a following exception was thrown on one of the devices:

```
No route to host
#0      IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:94)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      Future.timeout.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:944)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:93)
<asynchronous suspension
```

This was thrown (twice in a row) when the app attempted to connect to my server. To investigate further, I looked at the server logs and it turned out that all requests coming from this client were successful (code 200). I am unable to tell whether those two requests that ended with an exception reached the server though (but it seems to be likely based on the timestamps). After these two exceptions, the user continued making requests without problems.
I am wondering whether this might be some issue with the app / server or this is some kind of a network issue on the client's side.